ViroText does not appear when child of ViroARImageMarker
I am trying out my first Augmented Reality app.  I decided to use ViroReact.
I wrote the following practice code based on what i could understand about the ViroARTrackingTargets and ViroARImageMarker:

import {
  ViroARScene,
  ViroARSceneNavigator,
  ViroText,
  ViroTrackingReason,
  ViroTrackingStateConstants,
  ViroARTrackingTargets,
  ViroARImageMarker
} from "@reactvision/react-viro";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

// Define the oval image as a tracking target
ViroARTrackingTargets.createTargets({
  "ovalImage": {
    source: require("./puppy.jpg"),
    orientation: "Up",
    physicalWidth: 0.25 // The width of the oval image in meters
  }
});

const HelloWorldSceneAR = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Initializing AR...");
  console.log("Curent Text", text);


  function onInitialized(state: any, reason: ViroTrackingReason) {
    console.log("onInitialized", state, reason);
    if (state === ViroTrackingStateConstants.TRACKING_NORMAL) {
      console.log("searching for image ...");
      setText("Searching for image...");
    } else if (state === ViroTrackingStateConstants.TRACKING_UNAVAILABLE) {
      setText("Tracking unavailable");
      console.log("Not found");
    }
  }

  function onAnchorFound() {
    console.log("Found Puppy Marker!");
    setText("Hello World!");
  }

  return (
    <ViroARScene onTrackingUpdated={onInitialized}>
      <ViroARImageMarker
        target={"ovalImage"}
        onAnchorFound={onAnchorFound}
      >
        <ViroText
          text={text}
          scale={[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]}
          position={[0, 0, 2]}
          style={styles.helloWorldTextStyle}
        />
      </ViroARImageMarker>
    </ViroARScene>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <ViroARSceneNavigator
      autofocus={true}
      initialScene={{
        scene: HelloWorldSceneAR,
      }}
      style={styles.f1}
    />
  );
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  f1: { flex: 1 },
  helloWorldTextStyle: {
    fontFamily: "Arial",
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "#ffffff",
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});

When I run the command npm start, the application loads on my android phone.
On my computer monitor, I opened up the puppy.jpg image.  When I point my phone at the monitor, I see in my terminal console print the message "Found Puppy Marker!" which suggests the ViroARImageMarker triggered the onAnchorFound event handler.
But the ViroText with the Hello World message is not visible on my screen.  Did I do something wrong?
Note: If I place the ViroText element as a sibling to the ViroARImageMarker, then ViroText is always visible, and it doesn't track the puppy.jpg on my computer screen.
Also, here is the puppy.jpg image that I used:


UPDATE
I noticed the replacing ViroText with the element <ViroBox position={[0, .25, 0]} scale={[.2, .2, .2]} /> does cause the rendering of a 3D cube. So it looks like maybe I have some inappropriate styling values for the ViroText to cause it to be not visible.
